# Exposing different interfaces from single class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

We are trying to build some kind of a layer above the DAL in order to expose an interface of a certain repository methods using generics.

For example:

```
public interface A
{
    void Do_A();
}

public interface B
{
    void Do_B();
}

public void Main()
{
     Exposer<A>.Do_A();
     Exposer<B>.Do_B();
}
```

Is it possible to do that  ?

Comment: You provided neither a complete sample nor a complete definition of a specific problem you are solving. So what are you asking for?

Comment: Some kind of manager class that exposes the methods of an interface based on the <T> it gets, sorry if i am not clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tecnically, that isn't a "single class", since `Exposer<A>` is a different `Type` to `Exposer<B>`; however, ultimately, this doesn't look much different to most IoC/DI containers... if this was, say, StructureMap (purely for an example), you might consider:

```
container.GetInstance<A>().Do_A();
container.GetInstance<B>().Do_B();
```

you would, of course, need to configure the container to know where the concrete `A` and `B` implementations are coming from! Which for StructureMap [is shown here](http://flimflan.com/blog/HelloStructureMap.aspx), but there are [plenty to choose from](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx).

If you mean **directly**, then: no. You cannot have:

```
class Exposer<T> : T {...} // non-working code to implement the interface T
```

You *can*, however, have some class:

```
class Exposer : A, B {...}
```

and just cast:

```
A a = Exposer;
a.Do_A();
B b = Exposer;
b.Do_B();
```

Answer (score 1):

A type `Foo<T>` cannot implement (or extend) the actual `T`, as `T` is unknown at compile time. What you could do is expose a `T` as a property, and invoke methods on it. However, as Ondrej wrote, the question may be a little unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Are you describing IoC when you write?

```
Exposer<A>.Do_A();
```

Your Exposer class makes me think to [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) API:

```
ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>().Do_A();
```

If you want to get rid of the keyword `new` and get in a generic way an instance for a specified interface, take a look to this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) or check [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/)

Answer (score 0):

To choose which interface implementation you want when consuming a given class, you don't use generics, you just cast the class to the interface:

```
public interface A 
{ 
    void Do_A(); 
} 

public interface B 
{ 
    void Do_B(); 
} 

public class Exposer : A, B
{
    public void Do_A() { ; }
    public void Do_B() { ; } 
}

public void Main() 
{
     // the casts are redundant here,
     // because the interface implementation
     // is implicit

     ((A)Exposer).Do_A(); 
     ((B)Exposer).Do_B(); 
}
```

If you want to **exclude** members that are **not** implementations of members of the given interface, use explicit implementation:

```
public class Exposer : A, B
{
    void A.Do_A() { ; }
    void B.Do_B() { ; } 
}

public void Main() 
{
     // the casts are now required;
     // otherwise, you'll get a compiler error
     // telling you that the method is inaccessible

     ((A)Exposer).Do_A(); 
     ((B)Exposer).Do_B(); 
}
```